# What manga did Natsumi and the others read?

Tags: non-non-biyori

In episode 7, Natsumi started to read what looked like a manga magazine, and the others start reading it with her.

[image]

Does it come from a real manga? If it does, what manga is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the **Monthly Comic Alive**. It is a Japanese seinen manga magazine published by Media Factory.

[image: Cover]

<sub>Picture from [comicvine](http://www.comicvine.com/monthly-comic-alive-201309/4000-424394/)</sub>

This episode here is the July 2013 issue or as a number 201309.

---

I am pretty sure the mange she is reading here is **Omae o Otaku ni Shiteyaru kara, Ore o Riajuu ni Shitekure!** (おまえをオタクにしてやるから、俺をリア充にしてくれ！)

### Information

[image: Cover]

- Type: Manga
- Volumes: Unknown
- Chapters: Unknown
- Status: Publishing
- Published: Apr 26, 2012 to ?
- Genres: Comedy, Romance, School
- Authors: Aoki, Mutsumi (Art), Murakami, Rin (Story)
- Serialization: Comic Alive

> Kashiwada Naoki was determined to lead his high school life without
>   anyone knowing that he’s an Otaku. However, his classmate Bishoujo,
>   Koigasaki Momo, who was rumored among the girls to be a bitch, found
>   him out!? Before the despairing Kashiwada, she said something
>   undoubtedly surprising.
>
> “Aren’t you an Otaku? Then, make me into an Otaku!”
>
> The love story of two individuals bounded by an agreement of Otaku and
>   Riajuu starts!!

<sub>from [MyAnimeList](http://myanimelist.net/manga/39505/Omae_wo_Otaku_ni_Shiteyaru_kara_Ore_wo_Riajuu_ni_Shitekure!)</sub>

### Scene

The scene you see on the left page of the secound image is in the tenth episode.

[image: Page]

<sub>Picture from [Mangapark](http://mangapark.com/manga/omae-o-otaku-ni-shiteyaru-kara-ore-o-riajuu-ni-shitekure/s2/c10)</sub>

Comment: and the manga title?

Comment: @ShinobuOshino Im sry I thought the whole magazine :o I added the manga now in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The manga on the cover is [***Seikoku no Dragonar***](http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=64902). It has received an anime adaptation just last season (Spring 2014).

---

The manga that she is reading inside is [***Omae o Otaku ni Shiteyaru kara, Ore o Riajuu ni Shitekure!***](http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=77617) (lit. *I will turn you into an Otaku, so please turn me into a Riajuu*).

The pages are from the end of chapter 10. Below is the 2-page spread for comparison. Note that the art is not even distorted (which is usually done to avoid copyright problem), which suggests that it has received an okay from the author.

[image: Chapter 10 - Page 24-25]

[image: Chapter 10 - Page 28-29]

Comment: since both answer are correct I accept the first one, thanks :)